# How to evaluate this nested supremum-infimum formula?

Tags: optimization, supremum-and-infimum

How to evaluate this supremum-infimum, in which  $a$ is a positive constant? 
$$
\sup_x \inf_y (-xy + a |y|)
$$
I actually know the answer but I can't really prove it. I believe it is 
$0$ if $|x| \leq a$ and $-\infty$ otherwise. It comes up in optimization theory. Can someone show me how to prove this?

Comment: Which limit? $ $

Comment: What is the value of this expression? It's a limit.

Comment: No. $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x) = \inf_y (a|y|-xy)$, we see that $f(-x) = f(x)$, $f(0) = 0$.

If $|x|\le a$, then $xy \le |xy| \le a|y|$, and so $a|y|-xy \ge 0$, hence $f(x) = 0$.

If $|x|>a$, then $f(x) =f(|x|) \le (a-|x|)y$ for all $y \ge 0$, hence $f(x) = -\infty$.

Consequently, $\sup_x f(x) = 0$.